# Tracking Analytics(i.e: Google Analytics) without javascript/cookies but still has all data such as referrer, search keyword, browsers, etc

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, matomo

I want to track visits on sites like:

- BBS (Forums, phpBB, SMF, vBB) track your posts modifying your signature (bbcode).
- Emails track your email views using google analytics.
- eBay, craiglists, etc.. see who visits your posts.

I do some homework and found that actually I can do this through pixel tracking method and integrate it with google analytics. (http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2013/06/17/email-tracking-google-analytics/#sr=g&m=o&cp=or&ct=-tmc&st=(opu%20qspwjefe)&ts=1405324986 )

I already tried this, it's a good tips. However it still do not fulfilled all my expectations. It only track visits/opens and several other info that not important. 
I want to be able to track some user information such as search keywords, referrers, screen resolutions, browser plugins and page titles.

I know several methods using my own server as the host and distribute the pixel or using tiwik/google analytic/owa. But still cannot find the best way to do this.

Anyone ever experienced this before? Really appreciate if someone can help

Thx

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You're only going to be able to get so much without using JS to pass in that information. You're likely at the limit of what you can track now... but without any code it's hard to tell.

Comment: Yea... That's why i'm asking here. I have heard rumor someone can do it and get referrer with search keyword